# Как добавить autoconf, automake, libtools в msys (Windows)?

Tags: c++, autoconf, autotools

Для выполнения команды **./autogen.sh** в **msys** нужно дополнительно установить **autoconf, automake, libtool**. Я скачал эти библиотеки:

```
autoconf-2.61-MSYS-1.0.11-1.tar.bz2 
automake-1.10-MSYS-1.0.11-1.tar.bz2 
libtool1.5-1.5.25a-20070701-MSYS-1.0.11-1.tar.bz2
```

Но не знаю в какую папку в **msys** их нужно распаковать, таким образом, чтобы система увидела появление этих библиотек и команда **./autogen.sh** была доступна для выполнения.

---

Например я беру **autoconf-2.61-MSYS-1.0.11-1.tar.bz2** и распаковываю его в msys в корень этой папки. Перезагружаю программу и выдается такое сообщение:

```
You must have automake installed to call autogen.sh.
Get ftp://sourceware.cygnus.com/pub/automake/automake-1.4.tar.gz
(or a newer version if it is available)

**Error**: You must have `libtool' installed to call autogen.sh.
Get ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libtool-1.2d.tar.gz
(or a newer version if it is available)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда надо распаковать эти библиотеки?

Comment: https://packages.msys2.org/group/base-devel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зря скачали. В MSYS есть менеджер пакетов `pacman`. Запустите его из консоли, он все скачает и установит:

```
pacman -S base-devel
```